# Changes in getText().equals()?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

one week ago, i used this lines of code:

```
buttonAction.setText("Retry");
buttonAction.getText().equals("Retry") -> true
```

Today, when i recompiled my project (after the SDK+android studio update) i get:

```
buttonAction.setText("Retry");                             //called in BroadcastReceiver
buttonAction.getText().equals("Retry") -> false            //called in onClick
buttonAction.getText().toString().equals("Retry") -> true  //called in onClick
```

since `getText()` returns a `String` the two functions should return the same, or am i wrong?

**Edit:**

If i call following lines in `onCreate` Method,

```
    buttonAction.setText("Retry");
    System.out.println(buttonAction.getText().equals("Retry"));
    System.out.println(buttonAction.getText().getClass().toString());
    System.out.println(buttonAction.getText().toString().equals("Retry"));
```

they print:

```
    07-08 17:13:12.898  10343-10343/at.test I/System.out﹕ true
    07-08 17:13:12.898  10343-10343/at.test I/System.out﹕ class java.lang.String
    07-08 17:13:12.898  10343-10343/at.test I/System.out﹕ true
```

and if i call those lines in `onClick_ButtonAction` they print:

```
    07-08 17:18:34.913  10480-10480/at.test I/System.out﹕ false
    07-08 17:18:34.913  10480-10480/at.test I/System.out﹕ class android.text.SpannableString
    07-08 17:18:34.913  10480-10480/at.test I/System.out﹕ true
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe it's returning a char sequence rather than an actual string. I'm not exactly sure, but just assuming. The documentation says it returns a String, as you mentioned, but that's obviously not true?

Comment: hm, but since CharSequence is just an interface, i thought the underlying object should be the String i set before.

Comment: How do you know getText() returns a String? If this really an action button, then the reference manual tells something about text fields. TextFields return an editor object when getText() is called. Printing buttonAction.getText().getClass().getName() could help here.

Comment: It seems it depents on, where you call this method. (see updated question)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html, getText() returns an editable type. That is why it is returning false and you have to cast it into a String in order for it to be true.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It seems it depents on, where you call this method (see updated question)